# Redirect_uri in WSO2 API manager authorize API

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I am trying to call authorize API of WSO2 API Manager based on documentation:

```
**query component: response_type=code&client_id=<consumer_key>&scope=PRODUCTION&redirect_uri=<application_callback_url>
headers: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded**
```

Just wondering what is redirect_uri to be placed in here. 
Any help please

Reference : https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Authorization+Code+Grant

API Manager authorize API is able to identify redirect_uri with status code 302. and its returning status code as 200.

```
**127.0.0.1 - - [27/Mar/2017:11:56:42 -0700] "GET /authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<client_id>&scope=PRODUCTION&redirect_uri=https://localhost:9443/store/apis/info?name=LinkRealTimeAPIasd&version=1.0.0 HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Jersey/2.24.1 (HttpUrlConnection 1.8.0_101)"
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Mar/2017:11:56:42 -0700] "GET /carbon/admin/login.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 16005 "-" "Jersey/2.24.1 (HttpUrlConnection 1.8.0_101)"**
```

But it should return access token which will be further used to invoke APIs in WSO2-AM

Comment: Also can we use WSO2 API Manager to authorize client without Identity Server using AM's /authorize API. I don't have setup for Identity Server

Answer (score 0):

It is the Callback URL of the application with given consumer_key. (In API store screen, when you create a new application you need to enter callback URL to be able to enable authorization code grant.)

Comment: So the callback url is like another API call within API Manager. Or can we have callback url calling application to itself.

Comment: Using authorization code grant, the application need to redirect the end user to API manager login screen to enter credential. When the user is successfully authenticated, API manager will redirect back to application's callback URL with authorization code. The application will have to exchange the authorization to get access token. This is according to OAuth2 spec (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749)

Comment: Please let me know what is the default call back url do we need to set?
 is it https://localhost:9443/store/apis/info?name=LinkRealTimeAPIasd&version=1.0.0 ? and where do we exactly configure ? As i know it is configured in API store. but that is not working when  i provided call back url as redirect url when i was working with authorization code grant type

Comment: My URI : [link](https://localhost:8243/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<Clientid>&redirect_uri=https://localhost:9443/store/apis) and i am getting below error   <tr><td><b>invalid_callback</b></td></tr><tr><td>Registered callback does not match with the provided url.</td></tr>. Can someone please help me how to fix this issue. In API store i configured callback url as : regexp=(https://localhost:9443/store/apis)